# CSS background image not displaying (path of image is correct)

Tags: php, html, css, background-image

I am trying to add background image to div. For some reason I can't add picture. Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is code:

```
 #featured {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
background: url('http://www.mobiexplore.com/temp1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 99.893617021277%;
}

#featured p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 27px;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#featured-image {
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#featured-image .fluid-width-video-wrapper {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.featured-image img {
  margin-top: 44px;
}
```

Here is HTML/PHP part. It's a custom wordpress theme and I will only show you exact part of website where this DIV is used.

```
<div id="featured" class="grid col-940">

    <div class="grid col-460">

        <h1 class="featured-title">
            <?php
            if ( isset( $responsive_options['home_headline'] ) && $db && $empty )
                echo $responsive_options['home_headline'];
            else
                _e( 'Hello, World!', 'responsive' );
            ?>
        </h1>

        <h2 class="featured-subtitle">
            <?php
            if ( isset( $responsive_options['home_subheadline'] ) && $db && $empty )
                echo $responsive_options['home_subheadline'];
            else
                _e( 'Your H2 subheadline here', 'responsive' );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <p>
            <?php
            if ( isset( $responsive_options['home_content_area'] ) && $db && $empty )
                echo do_shortcode( $responsive_options['home_content_area'] );
            else
                _e( 'Your title, subtitle and this very content is editable from Theme Option. Call to Action button and its destination link as well. Image on your right can be an image or even YouTube video if you like.','responsive' );
            ?>
        </p>

        <?php if ($responsive_options['cta_button'] == 0): ?>  

            <div class="call-to-action">

                <a href="<?php echo $responsive_options['cta_url']; ?>" class="blue button">
                    <?php 
                    if( isset( $responsive_options['cta_text'] ) && $db && $empty )
                        echo $responsive_options['cta_text']; 
                    else
                        _e('Call to Action','responsive');
                    ?>
                </a>

            </div><!-- end of .call-to-action -->

        <?php endif; ?>         

    </div><!-- end of .col-460 -->

    <div id="featured-image" class="grid col-460 fit">

      <?php $featured_content = ( !empty( $responsive_options['featured_content'] ) ) ? $responsive_options['featured_content'] : '<img class="aligncenter" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/images/featured-image.png" width="440" height="300" alt="" />'; ?>

        <?php echo do_shortcode( $featured_content ); ?>

    </div><!-- end of #featured-image --> 

</div><!-- end of #featured -->
```

EDIT 2: Added HTML output:

http://pastebin.com/T78ZPQZK

Comment: can you give an example of your html? Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/tF62u/12/

Comment: its hard to tell with just this in the context, have you tried shorthand notation for your background like so: `background: url('http://') no-repeat #fff;` ... the syntax seems to be correct, so maybe there is other conflicting CSS in your code.

Comment: have you tried using `background-image: url( ... etc );` rather than just `background` - shouldn't really matter with the way it can be "shorthanded" but I don't trust every web browser to get the implementation the same.

Comment: @sulfureous I used "background-image: url" too but images was not displayed again....

Comment: does something simpler like a background color work?

Comment: @ogc-nick Background color is not working too....

Comment: Still seems to be working on the fiddle so it's something with your site's other CSS. Try using a developer tools, if on chrome hit f12 for firefox use firebug. http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/J4nUK/ That works in JS fiddle.

Comment: Post your output HTML please, as it renders on the page.

Comment: @YaMo Added HTML output as you wanted. Check pastebin in original thread.

Comment: @user2496520 If background:color isnt even working then it is a css problem that has nothing to do with your background declaration at all.

Comment: This is a *lot* of code to sift through.  Only provide enough to reproduce the problem, the rest is just a hindrance.  The markup doesn't even have the CSS provided in the question in it anywhere.  Add it and it works:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/cosnhvnz

Comment: Try adding a height value to your #featured div!  Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/M63EG/

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
#featured {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background: url('http://www.mobiexplore.com/temp1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 99.893617021277%;
}
```

to this

```
#featured {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff url('http://www.mobiexplore.com/temp1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg') no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 99.893617021277%;
}
```

or to this

```
#featured {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url('http://www.mobiexplore.com/temp1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 99.893617021277%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Cj Belo. Again image is not there. I tried with other DIV like '#featured p' and image was displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, with what you provided should work, just try adding a height value and background-size to the #featured div...also, somewhere along the lines in your html you have a php error...

HTML:

```
<div id="featured" class="grid col-940">

    <div class="grid col-460">

        <h1 class="featured-title">
            <?php
            if ( isset( $responsive_options['home_headline'] ) && $db && $empty )
                echo $responsive_options['home_headline'];
            else
                _e( 'Hello, World!', 'responsive' );
            ?>
        </h1>

        <h2 class="featured-subtitle">
            <?php
            if ( isset( $responsive_options['home_subheadline'] ) && $db && $empty )
                echo $responsive_options['home_subheadline'];
            else
                _e( 'Your H2 subheadline here', 'responsive' );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <p>
            <?php
            if ( isset( $responsive_options['home_content_area'] ) && $db && $empty )
                echo do_shortcode( $responsive_options['home_content_area'] );
            else
                _e( 'Your title, subtitle and this very content is editable from Theme Option. Call to Action button and its destination link as well. Image on your right can be an image or even YouTube video if you like.','responsive' );
            ?>
        </p>

        <?php if ($responsive_options['cta_button'] == 0): ?>  

            <div class="call-to-action">

                <a href="<?php echo $responsive_options['cta_url']; ?>" class="blue button">
                    <?php 
                    if( isset( $responsive_options['cta_text'] ) && $db && $empty )
                        echo $responsive_options['cta_text']; 
                    else
                        _e('Call to Action','responsive');
                    ?>
                </a>

            </div><!-- end of .call-to-action -->

        <?php endif; ?>         

    </div><!-- end of .col-460 -->

    <div id="featured-image" class="grid col-460 fit">

      <?php $featured_content = ( !empty( $responsive_options['featured_content'] ) ) ? $responsive_options['featured_content'] : '<img class="aligncenter" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/core/images/featured-image.png" width="440" height="300" alt="" />'; ?>

        <?php echo do_shortcode( $featured_content ); ?>

    </div><!-- end of #featured-image --> 

</div><!-- end of #featured -->
```

CSS:

```
#featured {
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
background: url('http://www.mobiexplore.com/temp1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 99.893617021277%;
  height: 500px; /*-- Specify to your liking --*/
}

#featured p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 27px;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#featured-image {
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#featured-image .fluid-width-video-wrapper {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.featured-image img {
  margin-top: 44px;
}
```

UPDATE / EDIT:

Better yet, take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M63EG/1/

Updated code provided above!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need the `!important` key. So, in `#featured` CSS class, write this:

```
background: url('http://www.mobiexplore.com/temp1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg') !important;
```

in place of:

```
background: url('http://www.mobiexplore.com/temp1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/19377249_ml-1024x6651.jpg');
```